# Include dynamic URL in location path

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I include my dynamic angular URL within my location path redirect?

```
#/{{getAccountTypeName($parent.user.account_type)}}/{{$parent.user.handle}}
```

Path:

```
$location.path(path); // include same dynamic URL as redirect within path
```

Currently I cannot get it to working within 'path'